# Bluemix application debugging not working in Eclipse

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

When I select "**Enable Application Debug**" in Eclipse, it is showing "**Establishing debug session**" in progress window but ends up enabling development mode.

[image]

When "Incremental Publish" is selected,  it gives error:

> Failed to create JMX connection.
>   The connection failed. Ensure that the remote Liberty profile server is started and that the user name, password, and port number are correct.

Also, /IBMJMXConnectorREST URL is giving 404 error.

Few things on the configuration done:

1. Using JDK 8
2. Debug perspective
3. App memory is 1 GB

Should we configure any other thing ?

**NOTE:** Java Cloudant Starter pack offered by bluemix is the app's codebase in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Activating debugging is performed in Eclipse by right-click on the application name under the correct Bluemix server, and selecting Enable Application Debug

Comment: Same was performed but it ends up with development mode

Answer (score 0):

Enabling development mode (and thus incremental publish) is one of the steps for turning on debug mode.  The tools ended up staying in development mode probably indicates that there are some problem on switching on debug mode after the development mode step is completed.

Can you provide the following information so that I can try to reproduce the problem?

1. What is the version of IBM Eclipse Tools for Bluemix that you are using?
2. What platform are you running on?
3. Do you see any error in the .log file in your workspace?
4. What is the exact version of JDK that you are using? Also, is it a IBM JDK or Oracle JDK?